# minimum css needed for jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm going through the css and combining declarations.

For example the header for the dialog is in ui-widget-header and ui-dialog-titlebar.

The issue is when I have jquery UI tabs, for example, within a dialog. Even through they are both scoped to different css selectors - there's still some conflict because the tabs inherits some of the parent's styles.

UI appends so many classes, it's a headache to go through it all (which I'm happy to do).

I'm wondering if anyone has whittled down the dialog css to only the css it needs (without consideration of other UI elements). So combining declarations into one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently used the UI Slider and I just used the selectors that are used with the script, I was able to get it down to two with that. Most of them you can scrap.. Like "ui-corners" for example. All that one does is round the corners. My advice would be to create one in jsFiddle and see what you need only for the functionality and then apply your own styles.

Or you could possibly go through the web inspector, edit the HTML and start hacking them out one by one to see which ones are actually hooked to the script.

Another option would be to put a wrapper DIV around the content and override the CSS with your own styles.

Best option though is probably to look at the documentation you can see what it is dependent on and under the theme tab it says which classes are used...

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Not really a very good answer but maybe it will help.

Comment: good points - these are all things i'm doing - just trying to get it down to the absolute base

Comment: Yeah I understand that. I actually try to stay away from jQuery UI if I can... mainly because of the excessive class usage. jQuery mobile tends to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the widgets don't really need many css styles.

- Dialog doesn't need any.
- Resizable needs most of its styles, because the handles need sizes so that they can be dragged.
- Tabs only needs the `.ui-tabs-hide` class which just sets `display:none` for the hidden panels.

Note that all widgets have a css style with their name (i.e. `.ui-dialog`) applied to their root element and that any widget specific styles are namespaced under it.

Comment: good points - i'm basically just whittling down/combining to get as few selectors/declarations as possible

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do for the jquery UI dialog with tabs is:

HTML;

```
<div id='unique_id'>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
            <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
$('#unique_id').dialog();
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qR8gK/21/

Comment: Hey Jeffery, thanks for the answer, but the css is still large due to the way UI breaks up the css for common items - whereas I'm trying to combine some of those, like the example I referenced in my question

Comment: Hi Jason, the question isn't very clear.  You are saying, "The issue is when I have jquery UI tabs, for example, within a dialog. Even through they are both scoped to different css selectors - there's still some conflict because the tabs inherits some of the parent's styles".  But there is no conflict in the example I posted.  What do you want to be different? As you can see here the styling is the same when they aren't inside each other: http://jsfiddle.net/qR8gK/22/